# How to create a function to append data to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
columns_list=['sport','home','away','selection','odds','tipster','stake',
              'is_won','profit','bookie']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_list)

def bet(sport,home,away,selection,odds,tipster,stake,profit,bookie):
    if profit > 0:
        is_won = True
    elif profit < 0:
        is_won = False
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[sport,home,away,selection,odds,tipster,stake,
                             is_won,profit,bookie]], columns=columns_list)
    df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
    #print(smemels has been inserted)
    #add market

bet(sport="football",home="sporting",away="porto",selection="sporting",
    odds=2.7,tipster="me",stake=500,profit=500,bookie="marathon")
```

I am trying to create an empty `DataFrame`  and then append new rows, by creating a function, so I only have to put the values and it inserts automatically. When I run the code `bet(...)` it doesn't really append the data.

Comment: You need to `return df` from the function and call as `df = bet(..)`. It creates a new object which you throw away currently.

Comment: Sorry, `return df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Why is it not? Your code cannot work unless you rebind the appended dataframe to some name.

Comment: that simply returns the result, it doesn't make it append to my df. I've sorted by equaling it to df

Comment: What are we discussing here? I already put `df = bet(..)` and you `return` the result, which is re-bound to `df`. This is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bet(**kwargs):
    '''place your code here

bet(sport="football",home="sporting",away="porto",selection="sporting",
odds=2.7,tipster="me",stake=500,profit=500,bookie="marathon")
```

See http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html

kwargs allows you to add keyworded  , like your trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Just add "global df" below your function header and argument inplace = True in append function:

```
def bet(sport,home,away,selection,odds,tipster,stake,profit,bookie):
    global df
    if profit > 0:
        is_won = True
    elif profit < 0:
        is_won = False
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[sport,home,away,selection,odds,tipster,stake,
                             is_won,profit,bookie]], columns=columns_list)
    df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True, inplace = True)
```

The first one tells the function to take global (outside of the function) df variable instead of creating locally a new one. The second one changes the dataframe instead of returning a new object.

Comment: Did you test this? The docs say that append creates a new object. Apart from the fact that using `global` like this is bad practice, I strongly suspect it doesn't work but cant test.

Comment: I added  df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True) and it worked now!

Comment: @ivofilipe you have some misunderstanding somewhere. That's exactly what I suggested in my comment, which you said wasn't what you wanted. Please don't use `global` as in this answer, it's setting you up for really complicated issues down the line.

Comment: ok, although without the global df it didn't work. it returned UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment